# Server Sent Events using PHP 8.x

Tags: php

Some years ago I wrote some SSE code under PHP 5.6 which has worked perfectly ever since. Recently I changed hosting provider and the code no longer works properly under PHP 8.1.

I wrote a very basic SSE to try to understand what's going on. It's here: http://johnlinford.org.uk/sse/

**Server (sse.php)**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

while (true) {
  $time = date('r');
  echo "data: Time is: {$time}\n\n";
  flush();
  sleep(1);  
  }
?>
```

**Client (index.php)**

```
<h1>PHP SSE test</h1>
<ol id="list">
</ol>

<script>
  var eventSource = new EventSource("sse.php");
  eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += '<li>'+event.data + "</li>";
  };
</script>
```

What I think should happen: A new date/time line should appear once per second.

What actually happens: Nothing for quite a while then all the missing one second updates are displayed in one go.

I experimented some more. I added several hundred bytes of spaces to the server echo message. This results in the client displaying updates more often but still not one line at a time. Is this some sort of cacheing problem?

I tried different browsers. Exactly the same problem on Firefox (PC and iPad versions), Edge and iPad Safari. It's not a browser problem.

Having torn out what little hair I had remaining, any assistance would be appreciated. I'm no PHP/HTML programmer, electronics is my thing, so please be gentle!

Comment: Can anyone shed any further light on this? It seems to be related to PHP version - the code works fine on PHP 5.6 but not on more recent versions. Unfortunately my current hosting provider doesn't support PHP versions earlier than 8.0. They maintain that there is no problem with their servers but they would say that, wouldn't they?!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the server side script (sse.php) takes a long time to respond.

You can see this in action by making a request to http://johnlinford.org.uk/sse/sse.php (you can try visiting the page from your browser aswell).

I don't see anything wrong with your code, it works as intended on my own server. Most likely, it has something to do with your hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jarmo. If it's the server side taking too long to respond wouldn't it miss some of the one second ticks? The server seems to be passing all the ticks on to the client but the client doesn't display them immediately. Also odd that increasing the size of the echo payload results in more frequent display updates.